# Tor Circuit failed to be created: destroyed

Tags: relays, circuit, protocol

Okay, so I'm running a few experiments on Tor for a course project. I keep on changing different relays to see the effects on response time.

But on some of the circuits, I keep on getting this message:

> Circuit failed to be created: DESTROYED

I was reading [Tor's spec-file](https://svn.torproject.org/svn/tor/tags/tor-0_2_0_5_alpha/doc/spec/tor-spec.txt) and found out that it's when the circuit gets destroyed w/o any explicit `TRUNCATE` message sent by the client.

Do you have any ideas how do I minimize the connections being destroyed? I think there might be a relationship between geographical distance. But then again, if it took too long to establish the circuit the message should have been `TIMEOUT` and not `DESTROYED`. So, it's probably due because relays might have to free resources from time to time? Or could be a whole different reason. Any ideas?

Edit: Since one (or more) relays send `destroy(circId)` messages to destroy the circuit along the path I was wondering if there's any way to figure out which relay initiated the circuit destruction step.

Comment: Just a note: The current version of the specification lives at https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt

Comment: IMO, if you could see which relay initiated circuit destruction, it could potentially be used to target specific relays that are known to terminate circuits. As far as circuits being destroyed in the first place, there's any number of connection problems that could happen between you and a relay. Add 2 more relays into the mix, and there's actually a lot of different things that could go wrong. Unless the problem is directly on your end of the connection, I highly doubt there's a way to minimize this.

Comment: Of course, Tor automatically creates additional circuits for better performance/anonymity, so it really doesn't matter if a circuit fails here and there.